# mail with attachment with stanard mail function

Tags: php, email

I need to send an email with an attachment with the standard php mail function.  I can't use classes like phpmailer. PHP verison 5.3.

This is working so far.

```
mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Exact duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for send mail with attachment

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```